# HIGHLIGHT <li> on click MAXIMAGE2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, highlight

im a very very noobie in jquery question, im developing a site using maximage plug in, it seem every work perfectly, but i dont know how to hightlight a

link when is click it on it, sorry for my terrible english.

Here's the website i'm developing.
http://aranasoluciones.com/azulejera/ejemplo-ok.html

and there is the js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
$('#maximage').maximage({
cycleOptions: {
fx: 'fade',
speed: 3000, // Has to match the speed for CSS transitions in jQuery.maximage.css (lines 30 - 33)
timeout: 0,
                    prev: '#arrow_left',
                    next: '#arrow_right',


                    },

                onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
                    jQuery('#cycle-loader').hide();
                    jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn(1500);
                    jQuery('.in-slide-content').delay(1200).fadeIn('slow');

                }
            }); 
        });
    $('.toggle').bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();
    $('#maximage').cycle('toggle');

});

$("#2").click(function(e) {
    $('#maximage').cycle(1); 
    return false; 
});

 $("#1").click(function(e) {
    $('#maximage').cycle(0); 
    return false; 
});

 $("#3").click(function(e) {
    $('#maximage').cycle(2); 
    return false; 
});




    </script>
```

PLEASE HELP!!!!! i will preaciated very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If i use the code

```
$("#maximage").cycle(1);

$("#maximage").cycle(2);
```

explicitly in your website specified using firebug the image getting changed. Could you please check whether the button with id "#1","#2" are defined and event defined for it are correct and the definition for click event should be defined inside $(function(){ }); or document ready. Please check the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
$('#maximage').maximage({
cycleOptions: {
fx: 'fade',
speed: 3000, // HastomatchthespeedforCSStransitionsinjQuery.maximage.css(lines 30 - 33)
timeout: 0,
                prev: '#arrow_left',
                next: '#arrow_right',


                },

            onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
                jQuery('#cycle-loader').hide();
                jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn(1500);
                jQuery('.in-slide-content').delay(1200).fadeIn('slow');

            }
        }); 
    });
$('.toggle').bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();
$('#maximage').cycle('toggle');
$("#2").click(function(e) {
$('#maximage').cycle(1); 
return false; 
});
$("#1").click(function(e) {
$('#maximage').cycle(0); 
return false; 
});
$("#3").click(function(e) {
$('#maximage').cycle(2); 
return false; 
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you need:

```
$("#nav li a").click(function () {
    $("#nav li a").removeClass("selected"); // OR $("#nav li a").css("background-color");
    this.addClass("selected"); // OR $("#nav li a").css("background-color","#0070ba");
});
```

However would suggest you to change your navigation link `id` to something more meaningful (instead of `#1 #2 #3` to `#nav1 #nav2 #nav3`).

Comment: Also, I think _technically_ IDs are not supposed to start with numbers. It obviously works in this case, but I think it would not validate. EDIT: Looks like it would be a CSS issue: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: Good point, never really knew that (never tried to start with number anyway), good to know.